# ODBC Connection User and password persistent

Tags: vba

Sorry my English. I using  Access 2016 32 bits and SQL Server 2019 I have the following routine

```
Dim tdf As dao.TableDef
Dim cadena As String
Dim db As dao.Database
Dim con As String

Set db = CurrentDb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If InStr(tdf.Connect, "ODBC;") <> 0 Then
        con = "ODBC;driver=SQL Server;server=miservidor;database=middbb;" _
            & "UID=miusuario;PWD=micontraseña;"
        tdf.Connect = con
        tdf.RefreshLink
        db.QueryDefs.Refresh
    End If

Next tdf
Set tdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

after run it i can see all rows in linked tables but when exit the access app and open again if i try read rows i obtain the error "the connection is from a domain that is not trusted" and the username and password are not set in connect property of tables, If i run my routine again, i can open tables without any issue. I created a pass-through query and put the same connection string on it, it executes fine even when I exit and run access again. Any idea or solution ?. Thanks